# Android how to change calendar date format

Tags: android, calendar

How to Customize calendar. Scenarios are
a).How to change calendar format ?
Ex : 1 to be displayed as 1st(Available)
     2 to be displayed as 2nd(Available)
     3 to be displayed as 3rd(SoldOut)

Comment: specify which class are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Call this code snippet whenever you want to build your personal suffix:

```
if (n >= 11 && n <= 13) {
    return "th";
}
switch (n % 10) {
    case 1:  return "st";
    case 2:  return "nd";
    case 3:  return "rd";
    default: return "th";
}
```